# update variable description via function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want update variation description, but can't find get it working with my code:

```
update_post_meta(347, '_regular_price', 3); // works fine
update_post_meta(347, '_number_field', 3*10 ); //this custom field works
update_post_meta(347, 'variable_description', "Whole price: 30$"); // not working
```

I think this "variable_description" is wrong..

Comment: `variable_description` should be `_variation_description`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the same String but in single instead of double quotation marks in the last line of code.